# in iOS, what's the equivalent of android.widget.Scroller from Android

Tags: android, ios, uikit

I am aware of the UIScrollView.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of android.widget.Scroller from Android in OS.

Is there such a view in iOS?

Comment: Have u seen UIScrollView ?
Does it not help your cause

Comment: you can easily find this answer by searching the web, i voted to close

Comment: UIKit.UIScrollView can't be the answer because Android's Scroller is intended for a different purpose